# Gnome-subtitles shows no video

Tags: gnome, 14.04, codecs, gstreamer, subtitle

When I open a subtitle here in Gnome Subtitles there is no video. Just the subs, the audio, and the black screen. It used to work in previous Ubuntu installations I had.

Just found out it could be a missing codec, `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`. It should solve this issue, but when I try to download it I get an error message that this package is not available.

Here you can find it: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/

Isn't it available to 14.04? I couldn't not even download and install it, shows error messages, can someone help me to understand it?

Answer (score 1):

**Pedro Castro** (the developer of Gnome Subtitles) added a Ubuntu 14.04 *Trusty Tahr* build of Gnome Subtitles version 1.3 to his PPA repository. I tested this new version and it's working like a charm. More info see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221500&p=13145232#post13145232) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221500&p=13146057#post13146057).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pedrocastro/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-subtitles
```

Comment: You don't need gdebi anymore. The Software Centre handle .deb files, including dependency resolution.

Comment: @[muru](http://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru): the problem with Software Center is that after you install the .DEB package it won't let you see which files and folders were installed in your operating system. But in GDebi you can open the package and click on the "Included files" tab: it will then show you all the files and folders that were put in your system, which can be a useful thing if (e.g.) you intend to create a symbolic link to a file (library, for instance) or folder. Synaptic and Aptitude are other good applications that also let you see the contents of an installed .DEB package.

Comment: You can edit your question to add that information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, updating to this version solved my issue. This is a newer version that is not in multiverse repo yet.

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/trusty/main/base/gnome-subtitles

Comment: I upgraded to webupd8 version but the problem persists 8-(